# How can I find the domain where the loss of precision theorem applies?

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision

I have

`f(x) = sin(x) - 1 + cos(x)`

I want to know for what values there will be catastrophic cancellation in the interval [`0`, `pi/4`] for single precision floating point ie. [1 sign][8 exponent][23 mantissa].

I know that when `x` is near `pi/4` then `cos(x)` and `sin(x)` will add to, close to, `1` and that will be a problem when subtracting `1`.

How do I figure out how close to `pi/4` I need to get before I start losing single precision digits?

I know that if two positive normalized floating point machine numbers are `x` and `y`, then `2^-p <= 1 - y/x < 2^-q` then at most `p` and at least `q` significant binary bits are lost in computing `x-y`.

Comment: Check [`eps('single')`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)

Comment: How large an error is "catastrophic" ?  Further, the loss of precision in a built-in function such as `sin` depends on how the function is implemented as well as the accuracy of your input value.   You might also find it easier to work thru this if you load `gmp` and the ExchangeCentral file `mptoolbox` .

Comment: If `x` is near `pi/4` then `cos(x)` and `sin(x)` are both around `1/sqrt(2)`, so they'll sum to around `sqrt(2)`, not `1`.  Did you mean `pi/2`?